# Having some trouble with using substring to find data from a string

Tags: string, substring, c++17

I'm trying to use c++ to interpret data in a string and then add it to an object. I have the adding the data to an object done pretty well but getting the data from the string is messing up. I'm not sure if the way I'm doing it is the best way but I'm trying to use substring to get the text.

```
int nonceSize = (fileDataStr.find("!nonce: ") + 8) - fileDataStr.find(" :nonce!");
int hashSize = (fileDataStr.find("!hash: ") + 7) - fileDataStr.find(" :hash!");
int prevHashSize = (fileDataStr.find("!prevHash: ") + 11) - fileDataStr.find(" :prevHash!");

std::string fBlockData = fileDataStr.substr(0, fileDataStr.find("~~~END DATA~~~"));
int blockNonce = std::stoi(fileDataStr.substr(fileDataStr.find("!nonce: ") + 8, nonceSize));
std::string hash = fileDataStr.substr(fileDataStr.find("!hash: ") + 7, hashSize);
std::string prevHash = fileDataStr.substr(fileDataStr.find("!prevHash: ") + 11, prevHashSize);
```

The code above is my c++ code, getting the nonce and the data works perfectly fine but getting hash and prev hash is where my code stuffs up. The problem is with hash, it is not terminating the substring and instead just returning the rest of the string. I'm not sure if this is related though I think because it is returning the rest of the string this leads to prevHash returning nothing. It is probably just a miscalculation on the sizes or something but I have spent ages looking at this and can't figure it out. Any help appreciated :)

This is what is in the string I'm trying to get the data from if that is important.

```
test
test
10

test2
test2
10
~~~END DATA~~~
!nonce: 6969 :nonce!
!hash: asdf69 :hash!
!prevHash: asdf68 :prevHash!
```

BTW, sorry if this post is poorly written/doesn't have enough detail. This is my first post here and therefore probably isn't done very well

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), [tokenizing](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/tokenizer/doc/index.html) or a full parsing solution (hand-coded or flex/bison)? Which version of C++ are you using? Please update the tags with the appropriate version.

Comment: You have your subtraction the wrong way round. `fileDataStr.find(" :nonce!");` is greater than `fileDataStr.find("!nonce: ")`; you are subtracting `start_position - end_position`  and ending up with a negative number. Then `substr` takes a `size_t` - an unsigned integer - and your negative number is converted to a very large positive number.